# Sylius Grid, how to sort by property that does not exist in entity

Tags: symfony, sylius

I have a grid that I created using Sylius that works perfectly.

One of the fields in my grid refers to the count of a collection property (Referees).

I am able to show the count of this collection (Referee Count), but I am unable to sort on on it, because the entity being used to populate the grid does return any sort of count on the collection.

The code looks as follows:

The fields in my grid.yml looks like the below:

```
     refereeCount:
       type: twig
       label: 'Referee Count'
       path: 'referees'
       sortable: ~
       options:
         template: AffiliateBundle:admin/referrer:_refereeCount.html.twig
```

and the refereeCount.html.twig:

```
{{ data|length }}
```

My referees property in Referrer.php the entity that is being used to populate the above grid is defined as below:

```
/**
 * @var Referee[]|Collection
 */
 private $referees;
```

As a result, the Gird displays the `refereeCount` correctly, but I am unable to sort on it.

Does anyone have any advice as to how I would be able to sort on the length of this column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a new refereeCount field to my Referee entity. I could not find another other way around it.